# Duplicate JLabel when setting text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I don't really have any code to show for the problem I add a JLabel to the JPanel, and I set the text to the mouse's current x/y position while the mouse is moving.

I'd appreciate if anyone could explain why this is happening.

PComponent.java

```
public class PComponent extends JPanel implements Commons {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5525789712337277886L;

public PComponent(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.setLocation(x, y);
    this.setSize(width, height);
}
}
```

PNode

```
public class PNode extends PComponent {

public PNode(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    super(x, y, width, height);
    this.setOpaque(false);
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
}

}
```

PInterface

```
public abstract class PInterface extends PComponent implements Resizable {

public PInterface(int x, int y, int width, int height, int nodeW, int nodeH) {
    super(x, y, width, height);
    this.nodeW = nodeW;
    this.nodeH = nodeH;
    this.node = new PNode[MAX_NODES];
    this.addNodes();
    this.registerInterface();
    this.pack();
}

private void registerInterface() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cachedInterface.length; i++) {
        if(cachedInterface[i] == null) {
            cachedInterface[i] = this;
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void addNodes() {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getWidth(); i+=nodeW) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.getHeight(); j+=nodeH) {
            PNode node = new PNode(i,j,nodeW,nodeH);
            this.add(node);
            this.node[index] = node;
            index++;
        }
    }

}

public void writeToNode(String s, int index) {
    if(node[index] != null) {
        if(node[index].getComponent(0) instanceof JLabel) {
            ((JLabel) node[index].getComponent(0)).setText(s);
        }
    }
}

public void writeToNode(String s, int index, int child) {
    if(node[index] != null) {
        if(node[index].getComponent(child) instanceof JLabel) {
            ((JLabel) node[index].getComponent(child)).setText(s);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void resize() {
}

protected abstract void pack();

protected void createTransparentInterface(int r, int g, int b, int o) {
    this.setBackground(new Color(r, g, b, o));
}

public static PInterface[] getCachedInterfaces() {
    return cachedInterface;
}

public int getNodeW() {
    return nodeW;
}

public void setNodeW(int nodeW) {
    this.nodeW = nodeW;
}

public int getNodeH() {
    return nodeH;
}

public void setNodeH(int nodeH) {
    this.nodeH = nodeH;
}

private static PInterface[] cachedInterface = new PInterface[MAX_INTERFACES];

protected int nodeW;
protected int nodeH;
protected PNode[] node;
}
```

ClientDetailsInterface

```
public class ClientDetailsInterface extends PInterface {

public ClientDetailsInterface() {
    super(0, 0, 200, 100, 100, 50);
    this.createTransparentInterface(255, 0, 0, 100);
}

@Override
protected void pack() {
    this.node[0].add(new JLabel("X:"));
    this.node[0].add(new JLabel("Y:"));
}

}
```

Canvas

public class Canvas extends JPanel implements Resizable, Commons, MouseMotionListener {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8374256772293662258L;

public Canvas() {
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    this.registerInterfaces();
}

private void registerInterfaces() {
    int count = 0;
    new ClientDetailsInterface();
    for (int i = 0; i < PInterface.getCachedInterfaces().length; i++) {
        if (PInterface.getCachedInterfaces()[i] != null) {
            this.add(PInterface.getCachedInterfaces()[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Loaded: " + count + " interfaces!");
}

@Override
public void resize() {
    // TODO add resizing code
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent mouse) {
    PInterface.getCachedInterfaces()[0].writeToNode("X:" + mouse.getX(), 0,0);
    PInterface.getCachedInterfaces()[0].writeToNode("Y:" + mouse.getY(), 0,1);
}
}
```

new screenshot
http://prntscr.com/6dp6rd

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are doing custom painting somewhere and you forgot to invoke:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

to make sure the background is cleared before you do your custom painting.

This of course assumes you are overriding the `paintComponent()` method. If you are overriding paint(...), don't. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent(...) method.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) because the problem is with your code and we can't tell what you code looks like from a picture.

Edit:

Don't override `getX()` and `getY()`. Those are methods of the component class used for painting components at a specific location.

Final Edit:

Take a look at [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the problem and the solution.

Comment: I have no custom painting going on at all at the moment. The red boxes are just JPanels.

Comment: @Quinton, Maybe you are using a transparent background somewhere. Anwyway we don't have time to play 20 questions. Did you read the second part of my answer? Where is the SSCCE?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new I will add the full SSCCE to main post in a minute

Comment: That is NOT a `SSCCE`. How do we compile and execute that code to see the described behaviour. How do you know the problem is even in those 3 lines of code?

Comment: I've updated the main post with the suggested advice and I also chose to stop overriding the width/height I posted a new screenshot of the result, I'm still not sure how I'd resolve this do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Quinton, why do I have to keep repeating myself??? First of all that code is not a SSCCE. How do we execute the code to see what you see? Where is the main() method? Where is the code to create and display the GUI. Also, did you not read my comment about "transparent background"? Why did you not confirm that you indeed are using a transparent background??? Pay attention to suggestions. See edit for my final suggestion.